# bootstrap tab no response on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/Kf7GF/

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

I copy the exact same code from bootstrap example, have no idea what's wrong

Comment: You have to load jQuery *before* boostrap.js. [It works now](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Kf7GF/1/).

Comment: Make sure jquery is before bootstrap.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery`

Comment: That pesky console ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because bootstrap require jQuery to work but you're currently load jQuery after bootstrap

You should either reverse the currently order between this two files or just remove `jQuery.js` in *External Resources* tab that you've included before and choose `jQuery` library by using the `jsFiddle` dropdown framework and it should work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kf7GF/2/